# How to parse only message from http response

Tags: r, xml

This is the response

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<error xmlns=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata\">
<code>null</code>
<message>Resource - ID not found</message>
</error>"
```

And I need to parse the string that is coming in  tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an XML parser. The `XML` package's `xmlParse` function does a fair job:

```r
XML::xmlToList(XML::xmlParse("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<error xmlns=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata\">
<code>null</code>
<message>Resource - ID not found</message>
</error>"))$message
#> [1] "Resource - ID not found"
```